# density of the rationals on the reals proof

Tags: real-analysis

The Archimedean property,
If $x\in R, y\in R, x>0,$ then $\exists n \in Z^+ $ such that $nx>y$

Now we want to prove that the rationals $Q$ are dense on the reals $R$.

The proof in the book Introduction to Real Analysis by Bartle and Sherbet start their proof by assuming that $x>0$. Why do they do this? In fact the Archimedean property like this where x  needs be greater than 0 is strange.

In other text books they say the AP is

if $x\in R, \implies n_x \in N $ st $x \leq n_x$
which makes more sense in the context.

Basically, why do they assume that $x >0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of $x$ is different between the two versions of the Archimedean property you're quoting. I will switch to different notation so that you can see the similarity.

The second property says:

> For all $r \in \mathbb R$, there is an $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $n > r$. Every real number has an integer bigger than it.

The first property says:

> For all $r \in \mathbb R$, and for all $u \in \mathbb R$ with $u > 0$, there is an $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $nu > r$. Every real number has an **integer multiple of $u$** bigger than it.

The second property is a special case of the first, with $u=1$. (Of course, you can also use the second property to prove the first, by applying it to $\frac ru$.)

The intuition behind the Archimedean property is this: all real numbers live in the same world. If you pick any real number as your unit, you will be able to measure all other real numbers in those units.

But we want our unit $u$ to be a positive real number, because we want $nu$ to get arbitrarily large as $n \in \mathbb N$ increases. This would not be necessary if we took $n \in \mathbb Z$ instead.

Comment: Im not sure I understand. If we let $x<y$ then $y-x>0$. Applying a corollary of AP we know there is an n such that $1/n < y-x$ which is equivalent to $xn + 1 < yn$. Its here in the proof we need to use that $x>0$. Because $nx > 0$, there is some natural number m such that $m-1 < nx < m$. Its here that I don't see how this proves the claim for numbers $\leq 0$

Comment: I feel like you're referring to a quote that I don't see in your question.

Comment: Above is how the book proves the density of $Q$ on $R$. What I don't understand is I can choose $x=-2, y=-1$, and I know I can find a rational number between these reals say $-1/2$, but the way the proof says we can't have $x<0$. If we did, we I suppose the inequality would just flip and we prove in 3 cases.

Comment: To get $1/n < y-x$, you are not applying AP to $x$, you are applying it to $y-x$, and we always know $y-x>0$.

Comment: Right but when we get to the line that says because $nx>0$, its unclear why this proof would work for $x<=0$

Comment: I'm not sure you realize this, but I don't own a copy of the book you're referring to. I have no idea what the line that says because $nx>0$ is. I have answered the question that you originally asked, which did not have anything to do with that line.

Comment: I assumed you didn't. The first comment is how the proof in the book proceeds. Let me clarify, they start by assuming that $x>0$ and $x<y$. This means $y-x>0$. We use the AP to say there exists a natural $n$ such that $1/n < y-x$ or $xn+1 < yn$. Because $nx>0$,$\exists m$ such that $m-1 < nx < m$.  Thus $m< nx+1<ny$ and $nx<m<ny$. Finally we divide by n and get $x<m/n<y$.      My question now is why are we allowed to assume that $x>0$

Comment: In *this proof* - not in the AP - you are right that there is no reason we are allowed to assume $x>0$, unless we consider a separate case where $x<0$. Also, the existence of $m$ really needs its own application of the AP, and if we're separately proving that application, we might as well drop the "$>0$" requirement and instead prove there is an *integer* $m$. Finally, we can't guarantee $m-1 < nx < m$ because this is false if $x$ turns out to be an integer; however, $m-1 \le nx < m$ is enough to conclude $nx < m < ny$.